Files in project are inactive after PyCharm upgrade and I can't edit them
I have upgraded to PyCharm 2024.2.3 (Community Edition) from much older version, now when I open older projects, .py source files show up, but most can't be interacted with (file wil not open when doubleclicking it) Files do exist and can be opened in notepad.
I have tried Repair IDE / Invalidate Chaches, even deleting .idea directory and reopening project.
I have no idea, what is happening, there are no error messages.

Any ideas?
